# Is the series expansion of $e^x$, $\sin x$ & $\cos x$ valid for any real $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

$$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$$

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\cdots$$

Are the above valid for any real $x$?

Comment: yes; the series converge pointwise for each $x$. In fact they converge ‘locally uniformly’, but not uniformly

Comment: Do you know the concept "radius of convergence"?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: Not only for reals, but for all complex numbers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that property locally holds for all analytic function. You can show that this property holds for the functions in question globally as well.

**Proof:**
The radius of convergence of a power series defined by $an$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $$
is
$$ R =  \frac{1}{\limsup |a_{n}|^{1/n}} $$
by the ratio test. For the above cases:
$$\frac{1}{\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}} = \lim \sqrt[n]{n!} =\infty$$
Note: To see the last equality one can use the [Stirling-formula](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling-formula)

Above I showed that the power series, which is in our case the Taylor series of the functions in question converges for all real numbers. Now we only have to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x) - T_n(x) = 0 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. To prove this one can use Taylor's theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x) - T_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} x^{n+1}$$

For $f(x) = e^x$:$~~~~~~~~~~~~$
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} x^{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^\xi x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = 0 (\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$ 
For $f(x) = sin(x), cos(x)$: $~~~~$
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} x^{n+1}\right| \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = 0 (\forall x \in \mathbb{R})$

So we can conclude that the Taylor series of the functions in queston are not only convergent but also are convergin to the corresponding function.

Comment: "Holds for all analytic functions" is definitely false. The radius of convervence is infinite for the OP's three functions, but is not so for all (real) analytic function. For example it fails for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Your formula for $R$ is not right either -- the limsup needs to be taken _in the denominator_, or else it must change to a liminf (of a sequence with elements in $(0,\infty]$)

Comment: Thanks for the note about the limsup being missplaced, changed it. I don't really understand your other comment, by definition an analytic function is a function that is locally given by a convergent power series.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask whether $e^x$ and its friends are _locally_ given by the power series. He asked whether the power series around 0 is valid _for all real $x$_. That is a property shared by exp, sin, and cos, but by no means all analytic functions.

Comment: I see your point, changing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Showing that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ does not completely answer the question.  The question is not simply do the series converge for all $x$, but do they converge _to the specified functions_.  The answer is yes, but simply computing the radius of convergence of the series doesn't show that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, modified my  answer to include the part that was missing.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you can use convergence tests to show that all three series have an infinite radius of convergence; that is, all three series converge for all real $x$.  However, that is not enough to conclude that they converge *to the functions specified*.  That requires further work.

The approach taken in most calculus books is to use a formula for the Taylor series remainder.  But there is another approach.  Let me illustrate the alternative approach in the case of $e^x$.  Let
$$
f(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots,
$$
which is defined for all $x$ because the series has an infinite radius of convergence.
By term-by-term differentiation, we have $f'(x) = f(x)$, and therefore
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{e^x}\right) = \frac{e^x f(x) - e^x f(x)}{(e^x)^2} = 0.
$$
Thus $f(x)/e^x = C$ for some constant $C$, so $f(x) = Ce^x$.  To find $C$ we evaluate at $x=0$: $C = Ce^0 = f(0) = 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 1$, $f(x) = e^x$.

Similar arguments can be given for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ (although it's a little trickier).  For details, see my book *Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*.